# Angular 2 - get json file names from http.get

Tags: angular, http

In a server directory I have a list of json files. I need to import each json **filename** into my angular 2 component in an array of string or other structure.

I tried to make an http.get to the web server using this service.

```
export class AnUtenteService {
   getFiles() : Observable<string[]> {
      return this.http.get(directory)
         .map(this.extractData)
         .catch(this.handleError);
   }

   private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      return body.data || { };
   }
   private handleError (error: any) {
   let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
   error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
   console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
   return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  } 
}
```

But when in my component I call anutenteservice.getFiles() I get this error: 
**Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**.
This is my component

```
export class OrderslistComponent{
  newsList; 
  errorMessage;
  constructor(private anutenteservice: AnUtenteService,  private http: Http)
  {}
  ngOnInit() {
     this.anutenteservice.getFiles()
     .subscribe(data => this.newsList = data,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

}
```

I don't understand where is the mistake. What should I do?

Comment: Looks to me like the request you are sending is returning HTML not JSON since the first char is "<". Please look at the "network" tab in chrome console and find the request this http service sends and look at the response to make sure it is JSON.

Comment: Are you using JSON.parse somewhere?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam the response type in network tab is text/html and the request that I send is application/json.. Is this the problem? How can I return a json type instead of html?

Comment: @Powkachu I tried to use it but the result doesn't change

Comment: @ndrn I am not sure if the res.toJson() will parse a text/html response. The bigger question is: is the response body a json string? can you post the response headers and body **(content)** here?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Response header:   Content-Type:text/html; 
                                                                charset=UTF-8

Comment: the body is an html file

Comment: Ah, yeah so there is your issue.. your request is incorrect or you dont have access to get the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this structure:

```
export class OrderslistComponent {
    newsList;
    errorMessage;

    constructor(private anutenteservice: AnUtenteService) {
        this.anutenteservice.getFiles.subscribe((data) => {
                this.newsList = data;
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }    
}
```

And add `Http` to your service class. Add this to your service class:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
}
```

**Update 1:**

Try changing the type, here:

```
  private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.text();
      return body.data || { };
   }
```

In case your response type is not a `JSON`.

Comment: I try this solution but don't change.. maybe it depends from the response type that is html instead of json..

Comment: @ndrn Check my update, hope it fixes the issue. I thought response type was JSON.

Comment: Using this instruction I have the html code of the page,  but what I have to do is reading from the server directory to get the names of all json files that are stored in this directory.. is there a javascript function that allow to read from this server directory?

Comment: You can read what the server allows you to read. Create in the server a json with all the file names if you want a list of json file names... I think you should contact the backend dev so he can give you the data that you need...